# Close form solution for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{e^x-1}$

Tags: integration

Is there the close form solution for the integral is given by 
  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{e^x-1}\,dx$$
where $\alpha>0$

Comment: $\zeta(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\alpha+1)$ [(MathWorld)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html#eqn14). So no.

Comment: Thanks barto. I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  & I=\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{\alpha }}}{{{e}^{x}}-1}}\,\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty }{{{x}^{\alpha }}\frac{{{e}^{-x}}}{1-{{e}^{-x}}}}\,\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty }{{{x}^{\alpha }}{{e}^{-x}}{{e}^{-nx}}}}\,\,dx \\ 
 & I=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\,\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{x}^{\alpha }}{{e}^{-nx}}\,dx}}=\Gamma (\alpha +1)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{{{n}^{\alpha +1}}}}=\Gamma (\alpha +1)\zeta (\alpha +1) \\ 
\end{align}
Note
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{x}^{\alpha }}}{{e}^{-a{{x}^{m}}}}dx=\frac{1}{m{{a}^{\frac{\alpha +1}{m}}}}\Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha +1}{m} \right)$$